# Processing: createShape() behavior changes when Class file extends PShape

Tags: processing

I'm just learning Processing. My background is in ActionScript.  I'm creating a custom class which draws complex objects.  As part of this class, I call createShape() a couple of times.  Things worked fine until I decided I needed the custom class to extend PShape.  Now it will not recognize the createShape() syntax I'm using, and returns an error that says "createShape() expects parameters like: createShape(PApplet, PShape)"

Here's the function, which returns a PShape object.  It works fine.

```java
    class MyClass
    {
      ...

      PShape makeTriangle1( float w, color c )
      {
        strokeJoin(BEVEL);
        PShape t = createShape(TRIANGLE, 0, 0, w, 0, 0, topBar);
        t.setFill(c);
        return t;
      }
    }
```

But when I do this, it returns the error I've quoted above:

```java
    class MyClass extends PShape
    {
      ...

      PShape makeTriangle1( float w, color c )
      {
        strokeJoin(BEVEL);
        PShape t = createShape(TRIANGLE, 0, 0, w, 0, 0, topBar);
        t.setFill(c);
        return t;
      }
    }
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PShape` class has a function named `createShape()`. You can view it on line 1441 [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PShape.java):

```java
static protected PShape createShape(PApplet parent, PShape src) {
    PShape dest = null;
    if (src.family == GROUP) {
      dest = parent.createShape(GROUP);
      PShape.copyGroup(parent, src, dest);
    } else if (src.family == PRIMITIVE) {
      dest = parent.createShape(src.kind, src.params);
      PShape.copyPrimitive(src, dest);
    } else if (src.family == GEOMETRY) {
      dest = parent.createShape(src.kind);
      PShape.copyGeometry(src, dest);
    } else if (src.family == PATH) {
      dest = parent.createShape(PATH);
      PShape.copyPath(src, dest);
    }
    dest.setName(src.name);
    return dest;
  }
```

Notice the arguments for that function are a `PApplet` and a `PShape`.

When you extend `PShape` and call `createShape()` inside that class, Processing thinks you're trying to call this function. Since your arguments don't match up, you get the error.

To fix this error, you could pass your sketch `PApplet` into the `MyClass` class and specifically call the sketch-level `createShape()` function:

```java
int topBar = 100;

MyClass mc;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  mc = new MyClass(this);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  shape(mc.makeTriangle1(100, #ff0000), 200, 200);
}


class MyClass extends PShape{

  PApplet sketch;

  public MyClass(PApplet sketch){
    this.sketch = sketch;
  }

  PShape makeTriangle1( float w, color c )
  {
    strokeJoin(BEVEL);
    PShape t = sketch.createShape(TRIANGLE, 0, 0, w, 0, 0, topBar);
    t.setFill(c);
    return t;
  }
}
```

However, I would strongly suggest that you refactor your code so that you don't need to extend `PShape` anymore. It seems very strange to extend a Processing class like that. Chances are you should be using [composition instead of inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). In other words, your class **has-a** `PShape`, not your class **is-a** `PShape`.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm approaching this the way that I would do in ActionScript, as that is my main frame of reference.  It seems that's probably the root of my problem.